# Coldfusion Lack of error information when instantiating a .Net reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll, coldfusion, ms-office

So I'm playing around with the Microsoft Office Open XML SDK, and trying to instantiate it's classes in my CF 10 instance.

I'm starting off with trying to create a [DocumentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.documenttype.documenttype(v=office.15).aspx) class, SO I have used the code:

```
writeDump(createObject("dotnet","DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentType","C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll").DocumentType());abort;
```

This gives me an error, though, with no useful information.

[image: ColdFusion Error with no information about type of error]

So I then read that you also need to include the namespace in the class information.  However this also results in an error, but with some decent information:

> Class DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentType not found in the specified assembly list.
>
> The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute.

I'm a little stumped on this now.  Am I doing some obviously wrong.

As a second point, is there a way of dumping all the classes that the DLL contains that I can reference?

### Edit

Having changed the code up as @Leigh suggested in the comments, to read:

```
writeDump(createObject("dotnet","DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentType","C:\Program Files (x86)\Open XML SDK\V2.5\lib\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll"));abort;
```

Produced this error in: `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jnbridge\error.log`

```
======================
13/05/2014 23:23:53
Java-side exception: com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ClassNotFoundException
Java-side exception message: java.lang.Class+EnclosingMethodInfo
Java-side stack trace: com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ClassNotFoundException:
java.lang.Class+EnclosingMethodInfo
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ClassInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.JNBDispatcher.construct(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.JNBDispatcher.call(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.server.b.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.server.b.c.p(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.server.b.c.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

.NET-side stack trace = .NET-side stack trace:

at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ExceptionFactory.throwException(JNBException e, Hashtable objMap)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ClassInfo..ctor(String name)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectHelper.getSubstituteProxy(String returnedType, Type expectedType)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.getSubstituteProxy(String className)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.getType(String className, Boolean noSubstituteProxy)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.isThreadTrue(String className, Hashtable threadTrue, ClassInfo ci)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.generateProxyClassMembers(ModuleBuilder module, ClassInfo ci, Boolean verbose, Boolean noSupporting, Boolean isJSharpCompatible, ReferenceValueData refValData, Hashtable threadTrue, Boolean mapEnums)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyAssembly.addClass(ClassInfo ci)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectHelper.getSubstituteProxy(String returnedType, Type expectedType)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.getSubstituteProxy(String className)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.getType(String className, Boolean noSubstituteProxy)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyField.genClassLiteral(TypeBuilder theClass, ReferenceValueOptions rvo)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.generateProxyClassMembers(ModuleBuilder module, ClassInfo ci, Boolean verbose, Boolean noSupporting, Boolean isJSharpCompatible, ReferenceValueData refValData, Hashtable threadTrue, Boolean mapEnums)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyAssembly.addClass(ClassInfo ci)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectHelper.getSubstituteProxy(String returnedType, Type expectedType)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.getSubstituteProxy(String className)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.getType(String className, Boolean noSubstituteProxy)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.isThreadTrue(String className, Hashtable threadTrue, ClassInfo ci)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyClass.generateProxyClassMembers(ModuleBuilder module, ClassInfo ci, Boolean verbose, Boolean noSupporting, Boolean isJSharpCompatible, ReferenceValueData refValData, Hashtable threadTrue, Boolean mapEnums)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ProxyAssembly.addClass(ClassInfo ci)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectHelper.getSubstituteProxy(String returnedType, Type expectedType)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ExceptionFactory.throwException(JNBException e, Hashtable objMap)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ProxyJarFile.close()
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.JNBProxy.generateJavaProxies(String[] classes, Options options, AppDomain dotNetAssembliesAppDomain, Hashtable refValueMap, Hashtable threadTrue)
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.JNBProxy.Main(String[] args)

Java-side stack trace:

com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Class+EnclosingMethodInfo
at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.ClassInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.JNBDispatcher.construct(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.JNBDispatcher.call(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.server.b.d.a(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.server.b.c.p(Unknown Source)
at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.server.b.c.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

Comment: The `.DocumentType()` at the end looks off. If you are trying to call the class' no arg constructor use the special `.init()` method. But for now, drop that part and just dump: `createObject("dotnet", "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentType", {path to dll});`

Comment: @Leigh That gives me the original screenshotted error.

Comment: (Edit) Could be it requires more than just the OpenXML dll. I have had that happen, and the errors were equally uninformative. Check the .net error log to see if it contains more details. It should be under either `jnbridge\` or the standard `logs\` directory.

Comment: Edited up to include the JNBridge Error log @Leigh

Comment: Unfortunately that error is not very informative either ;) It is all generic reflection stuff with no mention of specific classes. I only have v2.0 installed, but using `...\Open XML SDK\V2.0\...` for the assembly path worked for me w/CF10.0. Give it a try for grins. If you get the same error, try clearing out [the proxy files](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/767.cfm) (*except* `dotNetCoreProxy.jar`) , then retry it.

Comment: Hmmm  interesting, I'll give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: The namespace is already in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentType, so adding it again won't help -- hence the "Not found in the specified assembly list" error.  The ClassNotFoundException for Class+EnclosingClassInfo is just an artifact, and contains no useful info.  I notice that the DLL is for .NET 4.0 -- are you using an earlier .NET version?  Easy ways to see the available classes in the DLL: either use the proxy generation tool, or use the ildasm.exe tool that comes with Visual Studio or the .NET SDK.

Comment: @WayneCitrin - Thanks for chiming in. RE the duplicated namespace, that may just be a misleading error message from CF. CF10 still reports "not found in specified assembly list..." when using the correct path: `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.DocumentType`

Comment: I had no problem generating the proxies for this type, from the DLL.  Have you tried using the proxy generation tool?  Also, what about my question regarding .NET version.  The DLL requires .NET 4.0 or later.  Which one are you using?  (And are you using the 4.0-targeted version of the .NET interop tools, or the 2.0-targeted version.)  Contact me via JNBridge support for further discussion.

Comment: @WayneCitrin I was running .Net 4.  While I haven't got to the bottom of this, I have since used other parts of both the v2 and v2.5 SDK for creating classes in coldfusion.  It might be a case of me misunderstanding a code example and I don't need this function.  I have a feeling it's me doing something utterly wrong.

Comment: @Jarede This is probably a CF usage problem, which I can't help you with, unfortunately -- not a JNBridge problem.  If you still do think it's a JNBridge problem, email me at JNBridge support (you can find it on the web).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue before.  What happens is that the .Net code returns a class that there isn't a proxy for or throws an exception of type SomeClass.CustomException which jnbridge/CF .Net doesn't have a proxy for.  In both cases returning "ClassNotFound".

What I've done is add those classes to the assembly list in advance and instantiated and then dumped them (so the class proxy is built).

```
<!--- Instantiate our exception classes to ensure the proxies exists --->
<cfset nullObj=CreateObject(".net","System.Net.WebExceptionStatus","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll")>
<cfset nullObj=CreateObject(".net","System.Net.WebResponse","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll")>
<cfset nullObj=CreateObject(".net","System.Net.HttpStatusCode","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll")>

<!--- Create our Web Request class --->
<cfset webReq=CreateObject(".net","OURCUSTOMWRAPPER.HTTP.HTTPXMLWebRequest","C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll,C:\resources\utilities\OURCUSTOMWRAPPERLibray.dll")>
```

Comment: Yep, I too was [leaning towards missing classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642307/coldfusion-lack-of-error-information-when-instantiating-a-net-reference#comment36308342_23642307) as a possible cause. The problem is figuring out which one :/ When I have run into that issue, the logs usually contain the name of the offending class(es), but in this case there is nothing but generic reflection stuff...

Comment: If you have access to Visual Studio to do a project there or, otherwise, to use Powershell to try and instantiate and invoke the call to see what's happening under the hood.  Also check the documentation to see what classes are returned and if an error occurs which may help also.